# Moving process to Background doesn't work on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following problem when I try to put a process to the background:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 gcloud beta emulators datastore start --host-port=localhost:8484
$ bg

[1]+ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --host-port=localhost:8484 &
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.The futex facility returned an unexpected error code
```

This is an example of a gcloud beta process. But the error occurs for all processes.

Comment: I get this as well when using `npm start` to run a webserver